# How do you log systemd service starts,stops,failures as they occur?

Tags: logging, systemd

We have recently moved to systemd, and it has been quite useful. But I cannot find a way to log the starts and restarts of a given service.
I can use `journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=systemd -u some-service.service` to see the entries, but there doesn't seem to be a way to log it when it happens.

I know that I could hook into the `ExecStartPre=` or `ExecStartPost=` directives, but we have a lot of services. I'm hoping for a more general solution.

Comment: Try `ExecStart=/path/to/your/script 2> /path/to/file.log`

Comment: I would have to do that for every service. If I have a log of services, that could be a pain to change/maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method that I've for logging systemd operations for each service involves embedding "systemd-notify" calls inside your application. Whether this can be used to create an application history/journal of start, stop, exit operations is still TBD. Am currently working on a project to try this method. Gotta love systemd ;)